# move up/down and changing order javascript

Tags: javascript

So i have a table with rows and two buttons attached to a column.when I click the up button the row is going up otherwise down. The problem is that i want to actualize the order for that columns. For example if my row it's going up then the column order should have the order of the row that it changed.How can I do this? My function in javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".up, .down").click(function () {

     var $element = this;
     var row = $($element).parents("tr:first");

     if($(this).is('.up')){
         row.insertBefore(row.prev());

     }
     else{
          row.insertAfter(row.next());
     }

});
});




<tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['body'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ord'];?> <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
 </tr>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what you want is not to move the row, but to move the first 3 column of a row, and then the last column doesn't change, it is what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you want to do is update the text in the last column to indicate the new order of the rows.

I can think of two ways.  One would be to just reassign the order after any sort regardless of whether it's up or down.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".up, .down").click(function () {
    var $element = this;
    var row = $($element).parents("tr:first");

    if($(this).is('.up')){
      row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    }
    else{
      row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
    row.siblings().andSelf().each(function(i, el){
     $(el).find('.order').text(i + 1);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>Order</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2342</td>  
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 1 Body</td>
      <td><span class="order">1</span> <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2343</td>  
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td>Test 2 Body</td>
      <td><span class="order">2</span> <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2344</td>  
      <td>Test 3</td>
      <td>Test 3 Body</td>
      <td><span class="order">3</span> <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The other way is to store the order values in a variable to assign to their respective order columns.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".up, .down").click(function () {
    var $element = this;
    var row = $($element).parents("tr:first");

    if($(this).is('.up')){
      var targetRow = row.prev();
      row.insertBefore(targetRow);
    }
    else{
      var targetRow = row.next();
      row.insertAfter(targetRow);
    }
    
    var targetSortOrder = targetRow.find('.order').text();
    var activeSortOrder = row.find('.order').text();
    targetRow.find('.order').text(activeSortOrder);
    row.find('.order').text(targetSortOrder);
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>Order</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2342</td>  
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 1 Body</td>
      <td><span class="order">1</span> <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2343</td>  
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td>Test 2 Body</td>
      <td><span class="order">2</span> <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2344</td>  
      <td>Test 3</td>
      <td>Test 3 Body</td>
      <td><span class="order">3</span> <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Obviously, this does require you to isolate the text into a span or whatever.  You can do it without changing the markup, but it's somewhat more difficult.

**Edit:**  I had the logic OP was looking for incorrect in my example.  Here is a revised version.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".up, .down").click(function () {
    var $element = this;
    var row = $($element).parents("tr:first");

    if($(this).is('.up')){
      var targetRow = row.prev();
      row.insertBefore(targetRow);
    }
    else{
      var targetRow = row.next();
      row.insertAfter(targetRow);
    }
    
    if(!targetRow.length) return false;
    var targetSortOrder = targetRow.find('td').first().text();
    var activeSortOrder = row.find('td').first().text();
    targetRow.find('td').first().text(activeSortOrder);
    row.find('td').first().text(targetSortOrder);
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>Order</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2342</td>  
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 1 Body</td>
      <td>1 <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2343</td>  
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td>Test 2 Body</td>
      <td>2 <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2344</td>  
      <td>Test 3</td>
      <td>Test 3 Body</td>
      <td>3 <button class='up'>Up </button> <button class='down'>Down </button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hello. the idea is that when I press up button for the second row for ex the id should be the same as the id from the first row. only the other things to change. Understand me?

Comment: @Adiiia So the ID column (the first one) never changes as you reorder?  You're basically replacing the values of a row (except for ID) by pressing Up or Down?

Comment: yes, but actually the column order never should change.

Comment: That's what I wanna try to do

Comment: @Adiiia I've added a third snippet to my answer.  Is that what you're looking for?  It's the same as my second example but with a different target cell for the text replacement.

Comment: and if I want to change the row who should remain unchanged how should I change the code? becuase I can t see any including of his name

Comment: @Adiiia I would add a class to the `td` and reference that.  In my third example, I just referenced the first column with `.first()`.

Answer (score 2):

Will this help?

**PHP output HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Body 1</td>
    <td>
      <button class='up'>Up </button>
      <button class='down'>Down </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Body 2</td>
    <td>
      <button class='up'>Up </button>
      <button class='down'>Down </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
    <td>Body 3</td>
    <td>
      <button class='up'>Up </button>
      <button class='down'>Down </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Title 4</td>
    <td>Body 4</td>
    <td>
      <button class='up'>Up </button>
      <button class='down'>Down </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".up, .down").click(function() {

    var $element = this;
    var row = $($element).parents("tr:first");
    var swapRow = $(this).is('.up') ? row.prev() : row.next();

    if ($(this).is('.up')) {
      row.insertBefore(swapRow);
    } else {
      row.insertAfter(swapRow);
    }

    if (swapRow.children()) {
      var tempValue = row.children().first().html();
      row.children().first().html(swapRow.children().first().html());
      swapRow.children().first().html(tempValue);
    }

  });
});
```

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/jithin4u/hx7a0t7L/3/

Comment: @Adiiia, you may find the simplified version here. :)

Comment: @JamesJithin Sorry, what does the last condition ```swapRow.children()``` ? I remove it in the fiddle, and it still works. Thank you.

Comment: @JCarlos, it is prevent the first column value from getting swapped.